# ElasticSearch substring match

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a string like

```
/something/other/123
```

I want to be able to search 123. For some reason given that the string is indexed as keyword, when I attempt to do

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {"myfield": {"value": "*123"}}
  }
}
```

It gives nothing, why is that?

Comment: can u also provide your index mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

**Wildcard query works on the `keyword` field.** if you have `.keyword` subfield(if Elasticsearch generated the mapping for your myfield) then below query returns the result.

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "myfield.keyword": { --> note .keyword in the field name.
                "value": "*123"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its indexed like: `"myfield": { "type": "keyword" }`

Comment: I realise I need to use "myfield" without `.keyword` but I need to put `*` at the end too. Like `*123*`

Comment: @JiewMeng, its not the case if you just need the documents provided in the question `/something/other/123` as putting `*` at the end will bring any documents which have `123` as a substring while without it it will bring `any documents ending with 123`.  its a normal regex syntax and nothing to do with Elasticsearch though.

Comment: @JiewMeng were you able to find the exact cause ? and did you get a chance to look at my comment as mentioned it worked for me and this is how it should be